# When adding multiple file attribute to product entity it work in prod but throws NoSuchPropertyException in dev

Tags: orocommerce

I have added a multiple file data type to the product entity and it works fine in prod but throws an error in dev

[image: error message]

I tried clearing the cache and again it works OK from Prod but I get the following error in dev:

```
php bin/console -vvv  cache:clear

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true

 // Clearing outdated warmup directory...

 // Warming up cache...


In RuntimeReflectionService.php line 76:

  [ReflectionException]
  Property Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\FileItem::$product_plan does not exist


Exception trace:
  at /var/www/html/commerce/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:76
 ReflectionProperty->__construct() at /var/www/html/commerce/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:76
 Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getAccessibleProperty() at /var/www/html/commerce/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:979
```

I have had a look in the modules mentioned in both above messages and other attributes I created were not present either but not causing any issues.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Some caches are not cleared automatically. Try to run `rm -rf var/cache/*` before the cache:clear command.

Comment: That has fixed it - will add it to my list of things to try. - thanks!